# JQuery migrate 1.2.1 doesn't work with JQuery 1.10.x or greater

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-migrate

We're upgrading a large project from JQuery 1.8 to JQuery 1.11.x

When trying to use the migrate plugin it doesn't seems to have any effect above 1.9.x. We've checked the documentation which says it should work for all versions.

Here's an example that tries to select all the not empty input fields using an attribute select. The migrate plugin is included through the external resources.

http://jsfiddle.net/moefinley/kgf413xq/25/

```
$('input').on('blur', function() {
    $('#attr').text($('.requiredField[value!=""]').length);
    $('#prop').text($('.requiredField').filter(function(){ return $(this).val() != '';}).length);
});
```

Are we doing something wrong or is this a bug?

Comment: Well, `value!=""` would select fields that are not empty. If you want to select empty ones, you may want to try `value=""`. http://jsfiddle.net/kgf413xq/23/

Comment: @PitaJ "select all the not empty input fields"

Comment: My question text was wrong, it said "empty" when it should've said "not empty", I've corrected the question text, thanks. Of course this doesn't change the migrate plugin not working.

Comment: BTW here is the JQuery upgrade guide about the attribute selector - http://jquery.com/upgrade-guide/1.9/#attr-versus-prop-

Comment: @moefinley - You should indicate when you edit something so I don't end up thinking that I'm going crazy.